# How do I change the ID parameter for radio button form fields in Symfony 2.8?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

So I have this code to display one radio button option in a ChoiceType field.

```
{{ form_widget(form.persontype[0], {"attr":{"id":"student"}}) }}
```

based on reading the net (mostly discussions here in stackoverflow), it should theoretically change the ID of the radio button. BUT it's not working. Any ideas on how to get it work?

This is my Form builder code in relation to the ChoiceType field.

```
->add(
    "persontype"
    , "choice"
    , array(
        "choices" => array("student"=>"Student", "staff"=>"Staff")
        , "expanded" => true
        , "label_attr" => array(
                "class" => "normal"
        )
        , "multiple" => false
        , "required" => false
    )
)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have a look here : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L334
id is diretly in the form vars not in attr.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure its not meant to overwrite in an easy way as ichabrand already wrote before :)

Not sure if this is the answer but i've seen it another day:

```
{{ form_widget(form.persontype[0], {"id":"student"}) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This id is made with your formulaire name and your field name : "formulaire[field]", i'm not sure than you can overpass that.
If you want to add custom field, you have to add 'allow_extra_fields' => true in your form options.

Answer (score 0):

If you use default `form_div_layout` as your form components template, you can notice that attributes for each of your inputs generated using the next block:

```
{%- block widget_attributes -%}
    id="{{ id }}" name="{{ full_name }}"
    ...
```

So to change id, you have 2 options:

- rewrite `widget_attributes` by using custom form theme
- overwrite `buildView` or `finishView` of your form type and after call of `parent::buildView` just add some code to modify `vars['id']` of needed control